# Keyboard Input Return Key

Tags: c#, wpf, input, keyboard

I am programming a calculator in C#, and I am trying to add keyboard input to it. The problem is if I click a button on the GUI then the Enter/Return key gets focused on that. When the return key is pressed it then clicks that key again, instead of being handled by my KeyDown event handler. How can I fix this?

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Key.NumPad1:
            case Key.D1:
                addInput('1');
                break;
            case Key.Return:
                MessageBox.Show("Enter!");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: show us what you have tried

Comment: Added the event handler code.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle [`PreviewKeyDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewkeydown.aspx) event of your form. Then check if you want to handle the event, and if you do, set [`Handled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.handled.aspx) property of the event to `true` after you do.

That would probably look something like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    PreviewKeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(MainWindow_PreviewKeyDown);
}

void MainWindow_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Space)
    {
        Log("Intercepted space in preview");
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

---

Why do you need to set `Handled` to `true`? Events in WPF are triggered on several UI elements, in manner which depends on it's "*routing strategy*". When your event handler sets `Handled` to `true`, visibility of that event will be limited to other UI elements. Shortly, it won't be triggered in other UI elements. To learn more about details of solution above, read rest of the answer below.

---

There are some things that you need to understand if you want to properly use events in WPF. Events are attached to UI elements (text boxes, buttons, etc), and event handlers can be connected to those UI elements. Also, UI elements are organized in a tree structure. Each element has it's parent element, up to root UI element. As already mentioned, events are triggered on multiple elements depending on their "*routing strategy*". Multiple elements here means element at which an event is targeted and it's parents, up until root element. Event routing strategy can be following:

- **Bubbling**: Event is first fired for event target element. Then, it is fired for it's parent, then parent of it's parent, and so on up until root element (often this is Window)
- **Tunneling**: Event is first fired for root UI element, and then down UI elements tree, along the route to target element.
- **Direct**: Event is only fired for target element.

[image]

How is this related to `Handled` property? When event is using bubbling or tunneling routing strategy, `Handled` property is used to stop propagation of event down or up UI elements tree.

Now, why didn't [`KeyDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.keydown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event stop propagating when you marked it as `Handled`? Because `KeyDown` event uses bubbling strategy. This means that a text box would already handle KeyDown event, before it get's to Window handler where you set `Handled` to `true`.

For that reason you should use [`PreviewKeyDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewkeydown.aspx) which uses tunneling strategy. Your window handler checks the event, marks it as `Handled` if needed. If it's marked as `Handled` it will not be triggered down UI tree to event target.

You can view this as a convention in .NET framework. `PreviewX` are events which use tunneling strategy, and are counterpart of `X` events which use `bubbling` strategy.

[To learn more about Routed Events visit this MSDN page.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx#routing_strategies) You'll find MSDN is a good source of information about WPF.

Comment: I added that code it. No change. Still does what it did before.

Comment: I have the KeyDown handled right now through the event property of the WPF Window. What benefit would setting it programatically get?

Comment: You did not note that you are using WPF for your UI. Please check my updated answer for details. Events are more tricky topic for WPF than for WinForms.

Comment: Thanks. That makes a lot of sense for why it did not work. I'll give this new code a try.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Key.NumPad1:
            case Key.D1:
                addInput('1');
                MyTextBox.Focus(); // <-- NEW LINE OF CODE
                break;
            case Key.Return:
                MessageBox.Show("Enter!");
                MyTextBox.Focus(); // <-- NEW LINE OF CODE
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: In the button click handler I added this.Focus() to try and set the MainWindow to be focused. No change.

Comment: @Emrys90: Why try to set the focus to the window rather than the text box of the input? Can you handle the key press in the text box?

Comment: The text box is read only. I handle input by using the buttons or key presses to append the character, if it is valid input.

Comment: @Emrys90: I think you actually need to handle the keyup message. It comes after key down and it's probably messing you up!

Answer (score 0):

set Focusable to false:

```
<Button Focusable="False" Click="Button_Click" />
```